# How to change the default navigation "active-trail" class to something different (or add an extra class)?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

How do I change the default "active-trail" class on the navigation menu `<li>`-item to something different, or add an extra class to the current active item?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74162/how-to-add-active-class-in-to-the-menu-item/74169#74169

Comment: Is the menu rendered as a block? Are you talking about the main menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x) function to add or remove classes from menu items. This will target all menu's on the page though.

Probably easiest is to target the menu directly with this function `theme_menu_link__main_menu`. You have to put display your menu as a block though. For bartik there is already a block available.

**Steps**

- Uncheck **Main menu** at *admin/appearance/settings/bartik*
- Put main menu block in a region (e.g. header region)
- Now you can do:

  ```
  function bartik_menu_link__main_menu (&$variables) {
    $link = $variables['element'];
     if (isset($link)) {
      if (isset($link['#attributes'])) {
       $link_classes = $link['#attributes']['class'];
       if (in_array('active-trail', $link_classes)) {
        $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
       }
      }
     }
   return theme_menu_link($variables);
  }
  ```

If you want to style the main menu when it's not in a block you could use:

```
function bartik_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $links = $variables['links'];
  if ($links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $link_classes = $link['attributes']['class'];
      if (in_array('active-trail', $link_classes)) {
        // add or remove classes here
      }
    }
  }
  // return themed links
}
```